# Why do chlorinated silanes have lower boiling points than their methane analogs?

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, boiling-point, halides

The boiling points of the chlorinated silanes and methanes are given below:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
\text{Species} & \text{Boiling point (X = Si) / }\mathrm{^\circ C} & \text{Boiling point (X = C) / }\mathrm{^\circ C} \\
\hline
\ce{XH3Cl} & -30.4 & -24.2 \\
\ce{XH2Cl2} & 8 & 39.6 \\
\ce{XHCl3} & 31.8 & 69.2 \\
\ce{XCl4} & 57.6 & 76.7 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The chlorosilanes are expected to have larger dipole moments and stronger dispersion forces.  Why do the silanes instead have lower boiling points than the methanes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I checked the bromides (most data from [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=SFD30BvPBhoC) plus Wikipedia), and the same pattern holds. I also added silane and methane for comparison, which challenges the trend: 

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
\text{Species} & \text{Boiling point (X = Si) / }\mathrm{^\circ C} & \text{Boiling point (X = C) / }\mathrm{^\circ C} \\
\hline
\ce{XH4} & -112 & -161.5 \\
\hline
\ce{XH3Br} & 1.9 & 4 \\
\ce{XH2Br2} & 66 & 96-98 \\
\ce{XHBr3} & 109 & 147-151 \\
\ce{XBr4} & 153 & 189.7 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: And here are the fluorides, which seem to be more complicated (data less certain):

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
\text{Species} & \text{Boiling point (X = Si) / }\mathrm{^\circ C} & \text{Boiling point (X = C) / }\mathrm{^\circ C} \\
\hline
\ce{XH3F} & ? & -78.4 \\
\ce{XH2F2} & -77.8 & -52 \\
\ce{XHF3} & -97.5? & -82.2 \\
\ce{XF4} & -86 & -127.8 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: I don't see how one expects weaker dispersion forces for bulky halogens around carbon. Where does this expectation originate?